# How to prevent Activity underneath DialogActivity from getting TouchEvents on dismissal of DialogActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

Does anyone know how to prevent a touchevent from reaching the `Activity` underneath a `DialogActivity`?

I'm using the following code that allows the user to dismiss the DialogActivity when it is touched outside its bounds:

```
setContentView(R.layout.dialog_activity_options);
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);
```

However, if the `DialogActivity` (the green area) is showing above a clickable region sitting within the `Activity` below as demonstrated in the mockup below (the blue area) and you click outside the `DialogActivity` in order to dismiss it, the touchevent actually dismisses the `DialogActivity` **AND** results in the clickable region from being clicked. In my case, this caused the `DialogActivity` to be dismissed and a new `activity` to be started as the "blue area" started a  new activity through an intent.

How do I just get the `DialogActivity` to dismiss **without** passing the touchevent onto the `Activity`?

[image]